# How can I change captured image, title and description in Facebook send dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

From last couple of days I am trying to resolved this issue. I have facebook application which is only open in facebook where I have put facebook send dialogue button now I want to change image, Title and description available inside. Anyone know how do it ? However it is work in separate html or php page which is out side facebook.

I have tried to change "og" tag for title, description and image but its not work in application.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJZ45.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the og tags in the debugger after changing them: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have already done that many times. Its not update the send dialogue data.

Comment: in that case the data may be locked. that happens when there are a lot of likes on the url already afaik. what is the url anyway?

Comment: Thanks for your time but application still in development environment so it can not be shared and there is no like as well. It's working properly out side Facebook. Only having issue when I execute it inside Facebook.

Comment: well, the url must be public in order to make it work with the og tags, so why not add the url to your question? it´s hard to help without the url.

Comment: Thanks again for your handy input. I will take answer in consideration if there is no option to do it in development environment.